# Strings in R - Insert a desired/arbitrary digit between a string and digit

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a character vector that looks like this:

```
questions <- c("question1"  "question10" "question11" "question12" 
"question13" "question14" "question15" "question16" "question17", 
"question18" "question2"  "question3"  "question4"  "question5"  "question6"  
"question7"  "question8"  "question9")
```

I want to insert a 0 between "question" and single digit so that the character vector looks like:

```
 questions <- c("question01"  "question10" "question11" "question12" 
 "question13" "question14" "question15" "question16" "question17", 
 "question18" "question02"  "question03"  "question04"  "question05"  
 "question06"  "question07"  "question08"  "question09")
```

Notice that string "question" associated with double digits i.e. `"question10"` or `"question18` are unaffected.

I am new to pattern matching. I have tried the following code:

`gsub(pattern = "(\\D*)(\\d{1})", replacement = "0\\1", x = mydf6$Question, perl = TRUE)`

However, its not giving the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may use `sub("(\\D)(\\d)$", "\\10\\2", mydf6$Question)`. This approach (similar to the one posted) won't work if you have more than 2 digit numbers at the end of the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gsub("(?<=[a-z])(\\d)$", "0\\1", mydf6$Question, perl = T)
```

This subs in a zero, but only if the string ends with a single digit, preceded by a lowercase letter.

Comment: This is close but removes "n" from "question" and replaces it with "0". So, ``question1`` becomes ``questio01``?

Comment: I think it works with perl = TRUE i.e. ``gsub("(?<=[a-z])(\\d)$", "0\\1", mydf6$Question, perl = TRUE)``?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, you do need perl = TRUE

Comment: Can you explain what the regex term ``"(?<=[a-z])(\\d)$"`` and ``"0\\1"`` means?

Comment: Sure, so `(?<=[a-z])` is a positive look-behind, which asserts that from the match head position, the previous value is a lower case letter. `\\d$` matches a single digit, that must be at the end of the string, that's what the dollar sign means. Put those two together, and the pattern matches a single digit at the end of the string, but only if the preceding character is a lowercase letter, and not a number. We capture `\\d` in group 1 with the `(...)`, and replace group 1 with 0 + group 1. We reference the group with `\\group#`, in this case `\\1`